# Acquiring NSInteger Value

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I am trying to grab the value of an NSInteger and set a UILabel value to it. The code is as follows:

```
counter_.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [counterAmount intValue]];
```

where counter_ is my label and counterAmount is my NSInteger. I keep getting a "Receiver type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to id.

I'm not quite sure how to understand this. I appreciate of your help.

Answer (score 1):

`intValue` is an `NSNumber` method that returns a C primitive value. `%@` prints objects. In order to output a C primitive value you have to supply the type in the formatting string. `%d` is the type for signed integer.

As per the question, and as pointed out to me quite correctly by borrden below, the type being dealt with here is `NSInteger` rather than `NSNumber`. In iOS `NSInteger` is a typedef of `int`, so you're dealing directly with a primitive type. The NS prefix does not mean that its an object.

Comment: counterAmount is an `NSInteger`, so this answer is not correct.

Comment: Your implicit point that I'd misread the question is completely correct and I've edited my answer appropriately so that potentially misleading information doesn't persist.

Answer (score 1):

Since counterAmount is a `NSInteger`, you can not use `intValue` on it (since it isn't an object, you can't send **any** messages to it, actually).

Instead, use:

```
counter_.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counterAmount];
```

Now that being said, if you are displaying this value to a user you should really be using a number formatter so that it is formatted the way that they have set it up to display in the settings app:

```
NSNumber *number                = [NSNumber numberWithInt:counterAmount];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter    = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle           = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle; // Or whichever style is appropriate for your number.

counter_.text                   = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```